# 3dcart - Overlapping images in a single category

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have eight categories of products, and I am attempting to overlay an image over all products in a single category (sale). I am currently using 3d Cart, which has been difficult.

I'm pretty sure I should be looking at `#midcontent` for the images, but it is not category specific.  Any guidance would be very helpful.

```css
#mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    min-height: 600px;
    float: left;
}

#leftContent {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#midContent {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 600px overflow: hidden;
}

#rightContent {
    float: left;
    background: none;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#midContent img {}

.site_padding {
    /* padding:8px; */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: kindly post your code or better if you can show a demo using jsfiddle.net